# Putting 2 authors on 2 rows

Tags: titles, author-number, titling

I am looking for adding a second author with affiliation that will respect the same presentation. Using `\author1` and `\author2` doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to deal with it?
Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[ DIV=calc,
                                paper=a4,
                                fontsize=11pt,
                                twocolumn]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{titling}                                                            \newcommand{\HorRule}{\color{Red}   
\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
\pretitle{\vspace{-30pt} \begin{flushleft} \HorRule \fontsize{50}{50} \usefont{OT1}{pzd}{b}{n}\color{Black}\selectfont}
\title{blablabla}       
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large \lineskip 0.5em \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{sl} \color{Red}}
\author{Martial Foucault, }                                                         
\postauthor{\footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} Sciences Po \par\end{flushleft}\HorRule}
\date{}
```

The complete document looks like this (with only one author):

```
\documentclass[ DIV=calc,%
                            paper=a4,%
                            fontsize=11pt,%
                            twocolumn]{scrartcl}                        % KOMA-article class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                    % Package to use French language
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % Package to use French language
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}                                 % French language/hyphenation
%\usepackage[english]{babel}                                        % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{lipsum}                                                 % Package to create dummy text
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}              % Better typography
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                                   % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                                   % Enabling colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}    % Custom captions under/above floats
\usepackage{epstopdf}                                               % Converts .eps to .pdf
\usepackage{subfig}                                                 % Subfigures
\usepackage{booktabs}                                               % Nicer tables
\usepackage{fix-cm}                                                 % Custom fontsizes
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}                                                    % Custom sectioning (see below)
\allsectionsfont{%                                                          % Change font of al section commands
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                                       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    }

\sectionfont{%                                                              % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                                       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    }



%%% Headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                               % Needed to define custom headers/footers
    \pagestyle{fancy}                                                       % Enabling the custom headers/

\usepackage{lastpage}   

% Header (empty)
\chead{}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=40mm]{logo_CEVIPOF.pdf}}
\rhead{Juin 2015}
\setlength\headheight{30.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.0pt}



% Footer (you may change this to your own needs)
\lfoot{\footnotesize \color{Red}\texttt{Notes CEVIPOF} \textbullet ~2015}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\color{Red}\footnotesize page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}   % "Page 1 of 2"
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}



%%% Creating an initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
     \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.3,nindent=0em]{
                    \color{Red}
                    {\textsf{#1}}}{}}



%%% Title, author and date metadata
\usepackage{titling}                                                            % For custom titles

\newcommand{\HorRule}{\color{Red}%          % Creating a horizontal rule
                                        \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}%
                                        }

\pretitle{\vspace{-30pt} \begin{flushleft} \HorRule 
                \fontsize{50}{50} \usefont{OT1}{pzd}{b}{n} \color{Black} \selectfont 
                }
\title{Les \'{e}lections d\'{e}partementales de 2015}                   % Title of your article goes here
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}

\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}
                    \large \lineskip 0.5em \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{sl} \color{Red}}
\author{Martial Foucault, }                                                         % Author name goes here 
\postauthor{\footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} Sciences Po, CEVIPOF      % Institution of author
\par\end{flushleft}\HorRule}
\date{}                                                                             % No date



%%% Begin document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}           % Enabling the custom headers/footers for the first page 
% The first character should be within \initial{}
\initial{L}\textbf{es \'{e}lections cantonales sont mortes, vive les d\'{e}partementales ! Tel aurait pu \^{e}tre le slogan des inspirateurs du changement de la r\`{e}gle \'{e}lectorale visant \`{a} d\'{e}signer les nouveaux conseillers d\'{e}partementaux.}

\section*{Un nouveau mode de scrutin}
Pour la premi\`{e}re fois de leur histoire, les \'{e}lections cantonales sont devenues les \'{e}lections d\'{e}partementales. Au-del\`{a} du changement de nom, les conseillers d\'{e}partementaux sont d\'{e}sormais \'{e}lus par paire de candidats dans un m\^{e}me canton, r\'{e}duisant de facto de moiti\'{e} le nombre de cantons (2054) mais en pr\'{e}servant sensiblement le m\^{e}me nombre de repr\'{e}sentants d\'{e}partementaux (4108 contre 4046).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post working examples, not only fragments! `\author` is a command which internally uses a tabular for the `\and` specification, for alignment purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is given in the manual of `titling` -- just use a tabular environment for the line up, being wrapped up in a robust command, which can be handled over to `\author`

```
\documentclass[ DIV=calc,
                                paper=a4,
                                fontsize=11pt,
                                twocolumn]{scrartcl}    

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%Style   Name -- Name 
%        Aff. -- Aff.   
\DeclareRobustCommand{\morethanoneauthor}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Martial Foucault & Jean-Luc Picard \tabularnewline
\footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} Sciences Po & \footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} NCC1701 Enterprise - D \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}



% Other style:  Name  --  Affiliation

\DeclareRobustCommand{\morethanoneauthorotherwayround}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
   Martial Foucault & \footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} Sciences Po \tabularnewline 
   Jean-Luc Picard  & \footnotesize \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl} \color{Black} NCC1701 Enterprise - D \tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\usepackage{titling}                                                            
    \newcommand{\HorRule}{\color{Red}   
    \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}
    \pretitle{\vspace{-30pt} \begin{flushleft} \HorRule \fontsize{50}{50} \usefont{OT1}{pzd}{b}{n}\color{Black}\selectfont}
    \title{blablabla}       
    \posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\large \lineskip 0.5em \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{sl} \color{Red}}
    %  \author{Martial Foucault \and Jean Luc Picard }                                                         
      \postauthor{ \par\end{flushleft}\HorRule}
    \date{}
    \author{\morethanoneauthor}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the output of `\morethanoneauthorotherwayround`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, I did not succeed to keep safe the rest of my document with your commands. But your second presentation was exactly what I wanted to get!

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using package `titling`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand\HorRule{\textcolor{Red}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{%
\minipage{\textwidth}%
  \vspace{-30pt}\HorRule\par
  \Huge\bfseries\raggedright
  blablabla
  \par\vspace{1cm}\normalsize\normalfont
    \sffamily\itshape%
    \shortstack[l]{\textcolor{Red}{Martial Foucault}\\[1ex]Sciences Po} \qquad
    \shortstack[l]{\textcolor{Red}{Jean-Luc Picard}\\[1ex]NCC1701 Enterprise - D}%
    \par%
    \HorRule
    \bigskip%     
\endminipage}]

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Apparently you had the same idea about Jean - Luc Picard ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My only concern is now to put the rest of my document in the same page. I understand that you have used \blinddocument for your example but the rest of my own document does not appear once \blind is off.

Comment: replace `\blinddocument` by any  other word, eg "foo" and it should be on the same page. If not, then you switch to onecolumn.